JFrog Platform V2 extension for Azure DevOps failing on Self-Signed certificate
We run Azure DevOps (ADO) server and JFrog enterprise on-premises. The certificates used by these applications are all self-signed by our internal CA.
We are currently adding JFrog to our ADO server and configuring JFrogNuGet for a pipeline. The pipeline fails due to certificate errors:
##[error]Unhandled: self signed certificate in certificate chain
##[error]Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

A pem and crt certificate chain files have been created and tried in the following locations:

$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/_jf/security
$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/_jf/security/certs
$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/jf/security
$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/jf/security/certs
The build agent's home folder:

.jfrog/security
.jfrog/security/certs



The pipeline failed using any of these locations.
The documentation from JFrog isn't very clear on what to do here. On the extension document page, there is a very clear section titled, "Not Using a Public CA (Certificate Authority)?". This section doesn't indicate where things should go.
The section ends with, Read more about this in the JFrog CLI which contains zero data on setting up the CLI for self-signed certificates.
I am hoping there is enough detail here to assist on how to set things up.

Have you tried to test running the JFrog CLI like jf config add  on your agent machine without using pipelines? If the commands never work on that agent machine, it will probably not work in pipelines as well. Those marketplace extension JFrog pipeline tasks are published and maintained by JFrog, have you reached out to their support for assistance? It is also suggested adding JFrog tag and engage more insights from SO subcummunities.

Thanks, @AlvinZhao-MSFT, for the feedback. I am still learning the CLI and wasn't sure which commands I could use to "test" the connection for troubleshooting. I have been waiting for our Cyber group to give me access to submit a JFrog ticket. Yes, that would make sense, but unfortunately, it is not an option right now.

Thanks a lot for the update. I am not so familiar with JFrog CLI as well. As far as I know, that extension task also uses JFrog CLI to authenticate access to JFrog Artifactory. The test may help isolate the cause of the issue. Meanwhile, JFrog support can be a better resource for assistance. Thank you again for the sharing and efforts.
